# Linear Algebra Properties

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

*obs.: as this question is very relevant I want that the readers upvote this question*

I hope my question can be of general interest, for I have tried to solve with no results. The question is taken from the book of linear algebra authored by the brazilian mathematician Elon Lages Lima, and it's the following:

> **2.3** Be $E = \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{R}).$ For any $X \subset \mathbb{R} $, we put $N(X) = \{\varphi\in E:\varphi(x) = 0 \hspace{0.5cm} \forall x\in X\}$. Prove:

(b) $X \subset Y \Rightarrow N(Y) \subset N(X)$

(c) $N(X \cup Y) = N(X) \cap N(Y) $

(d) $N(X) = {0} \Leftrightarrow X = \mathbb{R}$

(e) $N(X \cap Y) = N(X) + N(Y)$

(f) $N(X) \oplus N(Y) = E \Leftrightarrow Y = \mathbb{R} - X$

I've been stuck with the idea in letter (b) of how is it possible to invert the "$\subset$" sign even though by definition I couldn't clear it out. Letter (c) was very clear to me. In letter (d) I didn't comprehend what it means. In (e) I don't understand why we have to sum the $N's$ and lastly, for (f) I'd like to know why $N(X) \oplus N(Y) = E$, this is, both sets just having one common element imply that $Y = \mathbb{R} - X$.

Comment: What is $\varphi\,$?

Comment: It's just a function.

Comment: The null function?

Comment: By the definiton, you can call it this way.

Comment: I edited the question for more clarification about $\varphi$

Comment: My suggestion is that you try to familiarize yourself with the definition of $N (X)$. Indeed, for example for b) if $X \subset Y$ then there are "more functions that cancel $X$ than $Y$", simply because Y is "bigger" and imposes more conditions on the $\varphi$ function

Comment: I encourage everyone to upvote the question because it's one of the most relevant we have here.

Comment: I didn't comprehend why $X \subset Y$ in b) implies $N(Y)  \subset N(X)$

Comment: The proof of b) is straightforward from the definition of $N$. A function that "kills" everything in $Y$ will "kill" anything in $X$ because $X\subset Y$. Try to convert the above statement into math lingo and you're done.

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo, because it is relevant, it has been asked many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. The set $N(X) = \{\varphi\in E:\varphi(x) = 0 \hspace{0.5cm} \forall x\in X\}$ contains the functions that cancel $X$. Furthermore, the function $\varphi\equiv 0\in N(X)$, $\lambda\cdot\varphi\in N(X)$ for all $\varphi\in N(X)$ and, if $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\in N(X)$ then $\varphi_1+\varphi_2\in N(X)$. That is, $N(X)$ it's a subspace of $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.

**b)** We want to prove that if $X\subseteq Y$ then $N(Y)\subseteq N(X)$. Let $\varphi\in N(Y)$. See that $\varphi(y)=0$ for all $y\in Y$. But for every $x\in X$ then $x\in Y$ and so $\varphi(x)=0$. I.e, $\varphi\in N(X)$, this is, the function that cancel $Y$ came from the function that cancel X, for $x \in X$ implies $y \in Y$ .

**c)**

- $N(X\cup Y)\subseteq N(X)\cap N(Y)$.

Let $\varphi\in N(X\cup Y)$ and $\varphi(v)=0$ for all $v\in X\cup Y$. In particular, $\varphi(x)=0$ for all  $x\in X$ and $\varphi\in N(X)$. Similarly, $\varphi\in N(Y)$ and then $\varphi\in N(X)\cap N(Y)$.

- $N(X)\cap N(Y)\subseteq N(X\cup Y)$

Let $\varphi\in N(X)\cap N(Y)$. In particular, $\varphi\in N(X)$ and then $\varphi(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$. Similarly, $\varphi(y)=0$ for all $y\in Y$. So, $\varphi(v)=0$ for all $v\in X\cup Y$ and then $\varphi\in N(X\cup Y)$.

**d)** Note that $N(X)=\{0\}\iff \varphi\equiv 0 = N(X)\iff X=\mathbb{R}$.

**e)** We want to prove that $N(X\cap Y)=N(X)+N(Y)$. This means that every $\varphi\in N(X\cap Y)$ can be written as $\varphi=\varphi_X+\varphi_Y$ with $\varphi_X\in N(X)$ and $\varphi_Y\in N(Y)$.

Fix $\varphi\in N(X\cap Y)$ and define:

$$\varphi_X(v) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } v\in X\\ \varphi(v) & \text{ if } v\in Y-X \\ \frac{\varphi(v)}{2} & \text{ if } v\in \mathbb{R}-(X\cup Y) \end{cases} \\ \varphi_Y(v) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } v\in Y\\ \varphi(v) & \text{ if } v\in X-Y \\ \frac{\varphi(v)}{2} & \text{ if } v\in \mathbb{R}-(X\cup Y) \end{cases}$$

- If $v\in X\cap Y$ then $\varphi_X(v)+\varphi_Y(v)=0+0=0=\varphi(v)$.
- If $v\in X-Y$ then $\varphi_X(v)+\varphi_Y(v)=0+\varphi(v)=\varphi(v)$.
- If $v\in Y-X$ then $\varphi_X(v)+\varphi_Y(v)=\varphi(v)+0=\varphi(v)$.
- If $v\in \mathbb{R}-(X\cup Y)$ then $\varphi_X(v)+\varphi_Y(v)=\frac{\varphi(v)}{2}+\frac{\varphi(v)}{2}=\varphi(v)$.

And then $\varphi=\varphi_X+\varphi_Y$.

Finally, for prove **f)** note that

$$N(X)\oplus N(Y)=E \iff \begin{cases} N(X)+N(Y)=E \\ N(X)\cap N(Y)=\{0\} \end{cases}\iff \begin{cases} N(X\cap Y)=E \\ N(X\cup Y)=\{0\} \end{cases}\iff \begin{cases} X\cap Y=\emptyset \\ X\cup Y=\mathbb{R} \end{cases}\iff Y=\mathbb{R}-X$$

Comment: It looks like you didn't prove in c) the strict equality, I didn't comprehend your letter d).

Comment: In c), if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$ then $A=B$!

Comment: Letter d) wan't so clear to me, I think it would be good to divide in two cases of implications.

Comment: n letter e) I am not sure how you got $\varphi(v)$ implying the $v \in Y - X$.

Answer (score 0):

For (b),  you can consider any $\varphi\in N(Y)$, i.e. $\varphi(y) = 0$ for all $y\in Y$. As $X\subset Y$ this does also hold for all $y\in X$. Therefore, we get $\varphi \in N(X)$.

For (d), you probably mean $N(X) = {0}$, where $0$ is the function being zero everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$.

In (e) you need the sum, as you can consider (w.l.o.g.) that  $X \setminus Y \neq \emptyset$ and $Y\setminus X \neq \emptyset$. Then, there exists points $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ which are not in $Y$ or $X$, respectively. So, any $\varphi\in N(X)$ and $\psi\in N(Y)$ satisfy $\varphi(x) = 0$ and $\psi(y) = 0$ but not necessarily $\varphi(y) = 0$ or $\psi(x)=0$. (take for example the indicator functions which are 0 in X or Y (respectively) but 1 elsewhere) Then, we have obviously $\varphi + \psi \in N(X\cap Y)$ but $\varphi + \psi \not\in N(X)$ and $\varphi+\psi\not\in N(Y)$. Thus, you need the sum.

In (f) the only common element is the $0$ which is zero everywhere. You can use (e) to get the equivalence, as $E = N(\emptyset)$. Then, the direct sum implies that $X\cup Y = \mathbb{R}$ (which is not implied for only a sum).